# About Using Perf to Measure TLB Miss Data of Redis

Tags: redis, performance-testing

I want to have a Redis optimization project. I wanted to know how many TLB misses my redis server generated during runtime, so I used perf stat to measure. But no matter how I adjust the test cases, the data obtained for dTLB loads, dTLB load passes, and so on are all zero. However, the page faults data display is normal. I want to know the problem.The commands used are as follows:
`perf stat -e dTLB-loads,dTLB-load-misses,page-faults <program>`

I hope to measure TLB miss data and try other tools as well.